# Can you use a bootable macOS USB created on a MacBook pro, to install macOS on another MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, ssd, bootable-disk

So my friend has a 2011 MacBook Pro. The laptop's hard drive crashed and no longer works. He bought a new SSD as a replacement, but he doesn't have a way to install macOS on this new SSD, because he cannot create a bootable USB from his old hard drive.

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan on it. Can I use my MacBook Pro to create a bootable USB with OS X El Capitan on it? So my friend can use this bootable USB to install OS X El Capitan on his MacBook Pro.

Comment: To answer your question, yes you can create a USB Installer on yours and your friend can use it. Your friends might also be able to install using Internet Recovery... "As the computer starts, hold down the Command (⌘) – Option (⌥) – R combination immediately upon hearing the startup chime. Hold the keys until the animated globe appears on the screen. “Starting Internet Recovery,” the message reads."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly normal to create a macOS bootable installer USB key on one Mac and use it to install macOS on any other Mac.

The bootable installer is not customized for a particular Mac hardware, can be used to install macOS on any Mac that supports running the particular version of macOS.

You can use your 2009 MacBook Pro to download OS X El Capitan installer from this link:

- [OS X El Capitan](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?ls=1&mt=12)
- [How to upgrade to OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT206886)

After downloading the installer, you can follow the below instruction to create to create a bootable USB installer:

- [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372)